# protractor tutorial step throwing "element not visible"

Tags: protractor

I'm new to protractor and am going through the tutorial.  The setup and *Step 0* worked fine for me but I had an unexpected error in *[Step 1](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial#step-1-interacting-with-elements)*:

```
$ protractor conf.js
[13:11:41] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:11:41] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Started
seeking `first`
seeking `second`
seeking `gobutton`
seeking `latest`
F

Failures:
1) Protractor Demo App should add one and two
  Message:
    Failed: element not visible
      (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.78)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Linux 4.4.0-87-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 43 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
    System info: host: 'pfuntner1', ip: '9.42.83.35', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-87-generic', java.version: '1.8.0'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.ZhadTr}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=60.0.3112.78, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
    Session ID: cf611f619dbf2069413885ed9bcbba17
  Stack:
    ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
      (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.78)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Linux 4.4.0-87-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 43 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
    System info: host: 'pfuntner1', ip: '9.42.83.35', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-87-generic', java.version: '1.8.0'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.ZhadTr}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=60.0.3112.78, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
.
.
.
```

I added debugging statements to `spec.js` to try to identify what element it can't find.  It appears to find the two input fields and the button fine but does not find the output field.

Here is my `spec.js`:

```
// spec.js
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should add one and two', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    console.log("seeking `first`");
    element(by.model('first')).sendKeys(1);
    console.log("seeking `second`");
    element(by.model('second')).sendKeys(2);

    console.log("seeking `gobutton`");
    element(by.id('gobutton')).click();

    console.log("seeking `latest`");
    expect(element(by.binding('latest')).getText()).toEqual('5'); // This is wrong!
  });
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Post your spec js also

Comment: `// spec.js
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should add one and two', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    console.log("seeking `first`");
    element(by.model('first')).sendKeys(1);
    console.log("seeking `second`");
    element(by.model('second')).sendKeys(2);

    console.log("seeking `gobutton`");
    element(by.id('gobutton')).click();

    console.log("seeking `latest`");
    expect(element(by.binding('latest')).getText()).toEqual('5'); // This is wrong!
  });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Now there are few possible things happening here

1. The element that is returned by element(by.binding('latest')) is not the correct one
2. There are multiple elements matching element(by.binding('latest')) and the first one is being returned to you

The element being returned to you is not visible on the screen. Chromedriver is very specific when it comes to taking actions on element which are visible to the user. If the element is not visible to user a automation shouldn't be able to simulate action on it (not 100% true, because some actions can still be taken).

So make sure you are getting the right element and there are no multiple matches